# Migration from jQuery 1.7.1 to jQuery 1.9.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have replaced jQuery 1.7.1 to jQuery 1.9.2 and i have seeing the following errors with some of my custom build ui script and the jQuery provided UI library as well. the followings are the error.

Also i have upgraded the jQuery UI library to 1.10.0

the followings are error that i have been facing there are more.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined  
'e.widget._close'  
(anonymous function)  
e.widget.close  
(anonymous function)  
'_on.blur'  
u  
b.event.dispatch  
v.handle 

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'menu'

cannot call methods on myCustomOverlay prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'isOpen'
```

is there any things that i have to take care? please guide me how to do a migration from 1.7.1 to 1.9.1

Comment: VERY vague, please provide code.

Comment: the error you mentioned sounds like one you would get from using an older(out of date) plugin with jQuery 1.9

Comment: 1) Have you already reviewed the upgrade guide at http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/.

Comment: 2) Are you using https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme ?

Comment: If you have to include the migrate plugin to fix your issue, you're better off using an older version of the library until you are able to solve the migration issues, the migrate plugin wasn't meant for being used with production code.

Comment: @Kevin, where did you read that? There is a [production version](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#production-version) of the Migrate plugin.

Comment: @dgvid I am not using github, and the code base is too big to explain, how ever i haven't followed the guideline yet. this is primary research that i am doing on local server.

Comment: @Kevin i have changed the plugin to ui 1.10.0 i still will require to check other plugins though. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Dom I have very big codebase scattered in mutiple places. can not provide the specific code. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of the old code base has been completely revamped, or deprecated in the latest 1.9 builds, and because of that a migration plugin has been made available to bring back some removed features to help transition your project to a newer version of jQuery.

You can find the jQuery Migrate plugin on their official download page [here](http://jquery.com/download/). You also have the Migrate guide that @dgvid mentioned [here](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/).

Comment: I think i have to go through the migrate guide first and change the plugins, thanks everyone for the help. I was looking for general idea and the best practices for the migration, because I knew what ever i was doing was not the good way by just copying latest release and put it in codebase. Please add the comment if you have some more helpful content. appreciate all of your contribution.